# If $N$ is independent of each $X_i$, is $N$ independent of $\sum_i X_i$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1,X_2, ...,X_n$ a sequence of discrete random variables i.i.d, and $N>0$ a positive discrete random variable, such that $N$ and $X_i$ are independent for $i=1,...,n$.

Can we say that $X_1+...+X_n$ and $N$ are independent?

Answer (score 2):

No. An example:

Let the $X_i$ each be the discrete uniform distribution on $\{0,\frac1n,\frac2n\,\dots,\frac{n-1}{n}\}$ and let $N$ be the fractional part of $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$. It's independent of any one $X_i$, identically distributed to them, and completely determined by the sum.

Comment: I think $X_i$ are meant to be discrete. Not much change in your example though.

Comment: I noticed that after writing it. Already edited.

Comment: How do you justify that $N$ so defined is independent of the $X_i$ ?

Comment: Can we say that $[N=n]$ is independent of $[X_1+...X_n=k]$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Even if you lock down exactly what $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{n-1}$ are, adding another discrete uniform to that evens out the probabilities of the fractional part to $\frac1n$ at each possible value. That's the independence.

Comment: @Anas: No. The fractional part of the sum is uncorrelated with the sum, but it's definitely not independent of it.

Comment: So, how did I come up with this example so quickly? I've done it before - the continuous version, at least. [AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h470013_limiting_distribution_for_eulerian_numbers)